# Handle multiple buttons with different API IDs in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, api, front-end, forms

Ok, so my scenario goes like this: I am building an API of financial transactions. Backend does not matter for this problem, the only thing is that the API has a route `/users/:userid/transactions/:transactionid`. On the frontend (PHP and pure JavaScript, no NodeJS BFF or anyhing like that, just plain old client side JS with axios library) I have a page with a HTML table showing all transactions. Each row of the table (each transaction) has two options: Approve or Cancel. I then created two buttons for each row with the corresponding actions. However I am having some trouble dealing with these buttons because they should call the API using the corresponding `transactionid`.

My current solution: I have defined all the `<button>`´s with the `id` of the HTML element being the ID of the transaction to be used when POSTing on the route mentioned above. The button `onclick` attribute is used to call the JS function that will execute the POST and the id of the HTML button is passed to the function to be used as the `transactionid`. Like this:

```
<button id="EG202090283" onclick="Transactions.cancel(this.id)">Cancel</button>
```

In this case, the POST request is sent to `/users/:userid/transactions/EG202090283`. Of course this is not secure because the user can simply change the button id and POST to another route. But I don't know another alternative and I'm looking for best practices about this.

The question is: how to link these two buttons (Approve and Cancel) to the desired transaction **only** and how to do that in such way that it is difficult for the user to change the `transactionid`? Is it using sessions, do I need a BFF pattern for this?

Comment: You can't prevent the user from fiddling with this if they really want to. E.g., browsers let you fiddle with the request itself. BFF doesn't prevent any of this. That's not what the pattern is for. E.g., I recently had to deal a "user-friendly" dropdown offering common values for a field, but the value I needed was greater then the highest available. It was a legal value, I just couldn't set it via the UI. So I opened dev tools in the browser (F12), opened the Network tab, found the POST request, right-clicked on it, and chose Edit and Resend, and changed the value manually.

Comment: So it's not really worth the trouble going out of your way to prevent this. It's the backend that needs to make sure that the requests are valid and that the application is in a consistent state. One thing you could do is store the id with the button's JavaScript object (DOM instance), or maybe use JQuery's .data() method, or if the id isn't really button-specific, you could also store it in some JavaScript variable (but be careful how you deal with global state).

Comment: Hmm ok, I´m using roles in the backend to prevent the user modifying a transaction he/she does not have access to. But that doesn´t protect two transactions with same authorization level. This should be sufficient then? And what did you mean by storing the id with the button´s JavaScript object? Could you explain it a bit more, please?